# Datatable sacar tfooter PDF

Tags: javascript, datatable

Hola amigos es que tengo una tabla, y esa tabla tiene un thead y tfooter, peor cuando hago el print o lo exporto como PDF me sale el thead pero no me sale tfooter y los necesito.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así me sale el print, sin el tfooter
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al configurar los botones debes especificar si deseas incluir el _footer_ o no. La opción por defecto es no incluirlo. Lee [la documentación](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Se debe ir a la libreria de datatable dependiendo la versión en mi caso era buttonhtml5.js y buttonprint.js ahi hay una parte de footer donde dice true o false dependiendo si quierenq ue se vea el tfooter de la tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No deberías modificar el código de la librería, sino proporcionar los parámetros adecuados al configurar los botones.

Comment: Tienes razon, lo mejor seria que en un javascript a parte pusieran esto mismo y configurarlo.

Answer (score 0):

debes incluirlo en los parámetros del botón ...
buttons: [
'excel', 'pdf', 'copy',
{
text: 'PDF land',
extend: 'pdfHtml5',
orientation: 'landscape',
pageSize: 'LEGAL',
footer: true
},